# html purifier - allow links?

Tags: html, htmlpurifier

Old problem with links and html purfier.
I'm using this code:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();  
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,b,a[href],i');  
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', 'a.href');  
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

But it doesn't work.
The input

```
<a href="http://www.google.de">search</a>
```

will be turned to

```
<a href="%5C">search</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off magic quotes. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: thanks! This did it! <?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function magicQuotes_awStripslashes(&$value, $key) {$value = stripslashes($value);}
    $gpc = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    array_walk_recursive($gpc, 'magicQuotes_awStripslashes');
}
?>

Comment: Please click the "checkbox" next to an answer to accept it, thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. Note (for those who may use this solution): in some shared-hosting servers, you may not be able to disable magic_quotes